# Leaving your store open on Shabbos

Tags: halacha, shabbat, gentiles, employment, transactions

If you leave your store open on shabbos for your non-jewish or non-observant workers to run, and you don't make any money from it (give all profits to workers) is that ok?

Comment: This is a big sugyah, primarily dealing with halakhot from the first few simanim from hilchot shabbat in the S"A O"C.  Very complicated, ask a qualified poseq.

Answer (score 8):

There are a lot of factors involved, but starting with one of the more basic ones: Shulchan Aruch (Orach Chaim 243:1ff) rules that if the store is known to belong to a Jew and that it's not the kind of business that is typically sublet to someone else, then it is indeed forbidden to have non-Jews work there on Shabbos, because then it becomes apparent that they're doing the work on your behalf.

Answer (score -3):

No,you can not.

Comment: Can you give a source?

Comment: What is the reason you can't?

Comment: You cant do business on Shabbos unless its Lshadech Habons and tinok Lilamo Sefer the zemer goes

Comment: That Zemer happens to be a review of Hilchas shabbos.